# After cancel or save print dialog the current window was not close

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel-5.4

when I print the data then it open new windows with all respective data of HTML page and in small amount of time open print dialog but when I cancel that dialog or close the dialog at that time the the current window not close.

Please suggest how to close back window of dialog box after close print dialog.

Here is my code to print data:

```js
$.ajax({
    url: "project/printProjectData?" + this.searchdata,
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'html',
    contentType: 'application\'html',
    success: function(html){
        var w = window.open('');
        w.document.open();
        w.document.write('<html><head>');
        w.document.write('</head><body onload="window.print()">');
        w.document.write(html);
        w.document.write('</body></html>');
        w.document.close();
        CheckWindowState();
    }
});

function CheckWindowState() {
    if(document.readyState === "complete") {
        window.close();
    } else {
        setTimeout("CheckWindowState()", 2000)
    }
}
```

but still not close the new opened window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the way to close the loaded window after print or cancel.

As I am print the data after onload event same we have to close the window on same onload event.

```js
printProjectData: function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "project/printProjectData?" + this.searchdata,
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'html',
        contentType: 'application\'html',
        success: function(html){
            var w = window.open();
            w.document.write('<html><head>');
            w.document.write('</head><body onload="window.print(); window.close();">');
            w.document.write(html);
            w.document.write('</body></html>');
            w.document.close();
        }
    });
},
```

Thanks all.:)

Answer (score 0):

// Just pass w object to your function so it can close that window using that object

```
$.ajax({
    url: "project/printProjectData?" + this.searchdata,
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'html',
    contentType: 'application\'html',
    success: function(html){
        var w = window.open('');
        w.document.open();
        w.document.write('<html><head>');
        w.document.write('</head><body>');
        w.document.write(html);
        w.document.write('</body></html>');
        w.print();
        CheckWindowState(w);
    }
});

function CheckWindowState(window) {
    if(document.readyState === "complete") {
        window.close();
    } else {
        setTimeout("CheckWindowState()", 2000)
    }
}
```

Comment: It's instantly close the new window, even not open the dialog

Comment: please check now i edited code may be its working now

Comment: as expected but not load data in print dialog

Answer (score 0):

you could use setTimeout, if you want to wait for n seconds and then close

```
var delayInMilliseconds = 1000; //1 second

setTimeout(function() {
  //your code to be executed after 1 second
}, delayInMilliseconds);
```